# How to add animated background

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i have a gif image and i want to put it in my iphone game background, the image is a moving scenery but when i put in my background its not moving ..How can i keep my background moving like the gif image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, animated gifs does not work in iPhone. However it is possible to have the same effect using *animationImages* property of UIImageView. Instead of setting single image, you can set array of UIImages as *animationImages* of the view. Then you can start the animation any time by calling *startAnimating* method.

Of course to have an array of images, you will have to extract the frames of the animated gif as different images and add them to your resources.

Answer (score 4):

FOr that you have to use the imageview and set its frame as background view.

Insert all your images used for creating GIF in Resource folder

Then use the following code

```
UIImageView *imgBackView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
NSArray *myImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1.png",@"2.png",@3.png"@4.png", nil];
imgBackView.animationImages = myImages;
imgBackView.animationDuration = 0.5;// OR WHATEVER TIME YOU WANT
imgBackView.animationRepeatCount = 0; // 0 = loops forever 
[imgBackView startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:imgBackView];
[imgBackView release];
```

hAPPY iCODING...

Comment: error: request for member 'view' in something not a structure or union

Comment: Please check Which controller are you using in the .h file. Is it UIViewController?

Comment: this is my .h file...


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

NSMutableArray *_targets;
NSMutableArray *_projectiles;
NSMutableArray *_nottargets;


@interface BaloonGame : CCLayer
{

 
}

+(id) scene;

int _projectilesDestroyed;
int _timer60;
int _timerStatus;
int _funcOnPause;
@end

Comment: FOr that you have to use the imageview and set its frame as background view. (what does this line mean ) ,,i just copied the code what do i have to addd before it

Comment: Buddy your question is for cocos2D and I have replied for viewControllers. Kindly add the tag of cocos2D. So that theres no confusion.

Comment: sorry dude.. m also newbie in cocos2D.. :(